# Intersection sets in C

Tags: c

Newbie new programmer here. Currently attempting a C question in which I have to input two sets from the the user and print similar elements between them ie union set. I did get the answer but for some reason I cannot store the similar elements in a third array. I did get codes on the net but want to know why this doesn't work. Take a look at the code for a better understanding :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{
    system("cls");
    int i, j, temp=0, a[10], b[10], r[10]; //a and b=input sets r=resultant set
    printf("Enter first set :-\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
    }
    printf("Enter second set :-\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++);
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
            {
                r[temp]=a[i]; /* If i make a printf here and print the elements directly here and here then it works but storing it in a third array gives me a garbage value when printed */
                temp++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Resultant array is ");
    for(i=0;i<=temp;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",r[i]); //Always only 2 garbage values would be printed
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your original sets have 10 elements each, so the union might have any size from 10 to 20. You also seem to add an element to the third set only if it is in both sets; that's the intersection, not a union.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Also no check is made in `r[]` for repetition.

Comment: There's a syntax mishap whereby you're using `r[temp==a[i]` to check for equality, while I assume you actually want assignment.

Comment: @M Oehm OMG you are right, i re-checked in my book and it says "Find and print elements present in both the sets i.e union elements". Printing mistake I suppose?

Comment: Perhaps `r[10]` is wrong for a union. It can have all the `a`s along with all the `b`s. That makes a possibility of 20 items

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=temp;i++)` is printing one element too many. The last is either ininitialised, or if `temp==10`, undefined behaviour.

Comment: This: `for(j=0;j<10;j++);` is a loop without body, or rather the body is the empty statement terminated by the semicolon. Remove that semicolon and make the change you've already made to your post, where you correct the comparison for assignment and your intersection code should work.

Comment: That is why two garbage values: the first is written to `r[]` after the empty loop terminates. The second is because of the faulty print loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane yup, you are right, still the same problem though

Comment: Please make up your mind - intersection, union, or is it going to be the superset

Comment: @MOehm oh. my god. You are a lifesaver, IT WORKS! Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to change `==` operator to `=` operator in this line

```
r[temp]==a[i]
```

`==` is the comparison operator and `=` is the assignment operator.

2- Your code calculates the intersection of two sets[1] (i.e. common elements between two sets), not the union.

3- You can use `r` to calculate union of two sets. Remember that union of two sets is the set of all elements in both sets, with common ones repeated only once.

4- Your final result should be either stored in an array with its size being sum of sizes of the input sets(in your case 20), or in a dynamically allocated array.

[1] I assume that the input arrays are sets, i.e. no redundant elements, even though you never check if that's the case.

Comment: That was a mistake I made while editing the post, it was already =... still doesnt work though

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is at following line;

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++);
```

here you are adding `semicolon` at the end, which makes the loop to run with out going to next line and making `j = 10` in your code.

remove `semicolon` and do like this

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
```

Also in the last `for loop` modify as follows;

```
for(i=0;i<temp;i++) // remove i <= temp, otherwise it will print garbage value for last entry
{
   printf("%d ",r[i]); //Always only 2 garbage values would be printed
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the for loop of j you have added semicolon, remove the semicolon and it will work properly.